# Media query for image to work on Desktop and Mobile

Tags: css, html, media-queries, responsive-images

I have a background image on my website which works fine on Desktop but when I try to view the website on Mobile the image disappear. How can I fix this so it is responsive? I have already added media query and try to fix this using online resources but I am not sure what I am missing.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 650px){
  header.page-header {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1040499/pexels-photo-1040499.jpeg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-attachment: scroll;
}}

header.page-header .intro {
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

header.page-header .intro p {
  font-family: 'Old Standard TT', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

header.page-header .intro h1 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  header.page-header .intro {
    padding-top: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
  }
  
  header.page-header .intro p {
    font-family: 'Old Standard TT', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
  
  header.page-header .intro h1 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 65px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="page-header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="intro">
      <p>Hello.</p>
      <a class="scroll-trigger" href="#about">
        <div class="scroll-down">
          <span>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-4x"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: First of your HTML markup contains errors. Second the image will only show on a screen wider than 650px so not on mobile.

Comment: I tried changing 650px to smaller value. But same problem. Could you help me fix it?

Comment: Just remove the media query

Comment: remove media query bro

Comment: Your media query only sets the background image to your header when the screen is wider than 650px. This means that on narrow mobile devices, there will be no image and that's why your header appears blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove media query from your CSS

```
@media screen and (min-width: 650px){
    // CODE
}
```

if you write this in your CSS, that code apply only when your screen resolution size is grater than 650px or `min-width: 650px`

**EDIT**

In your site there is `.header.page-header` class contains `(min-width: 500px)` so, remove it and your problem solved.

replace `background-size: 100%` to `background-size: cover`

```css
header.page-header {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1040499/pexels-photo-1040499.jpeg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-attachment: scroll;
}

header.page-header .intro {
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

header.page-header .intro p {
  font-family: 'Old Standard TT', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

header.page-header .intro h1 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  header.page-header .intro {
    padding-top: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
  }
  
  header.page-header .intro p {
    font-family: 'Old Standard TT', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
  
  header.page-header .intro h1 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 65px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="page-header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="intro">
      <p>Hello.</p>
      <a class="scroll-trigger" href="#about">
        <div class="scroll-down">
          <span>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-4x"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I removed the media query but still image does not appear in mobile

Comment: open this post and run this snippet in your mobile, it works fine

Comment: Thank it worked.One more question - On mobile view some header contents seems to be missing. Could you check it for me?

Comment: which content is missing ?

Comment: Header is out of place, not formatted. I wish I could upvote, do not have much reputation sorry.

Comment: i added this line check replace `background-size: 100%` to `background-size: cover`

Comment: Thanks much appreciated